# Why my code is not providing the same results in different IDEs

Tags: python, pycharm, ide, execution

I tried this code in `PyCharm` but it was returning area as zero. But when I tried in Jupyter Notebook it was showing correct output. I am just learning to code. What could be the reason for this error?

```
  class Square:
    def __init__(self, height ="0", width="0"):
        self.height = height
        self.width = width
    @property
    def height(self):
        print("Retrieve the height value")
        return self.__height
    @height.setter
    def height(self,value):
        if value.isdigit():
            self.__height = value
        else:
            print("Enter a number for height")


    @property
    def width(self):
        print("Retrieve the width value")
        return self.__width
    @width.setter
    def width(self,value):
        if value.isdigit():
            self.__width = value
        else:
            print("Enter a number for width")


    def get_area(self):
        return int(self.__height) * int(self.__width)


def main():
    square =Square()
    height = input("Enter the height")
    width = input("Enter the width")
    square.height = height
    square.width = width
    print("Height is ", square.height)
    print("Width is ", square.width)
    print("Area is ", square.get_area())


main()
```

Comment: Not sure why Pycharm is behaving differently.  Are you using Python 2 or Python 3?  Also, it's very strange to be storing `width` and `height` as strings.  Why not store them as numbers?  And a square with unequal sides isn't a square, it's a rectangle.

Comment: I just tried your code in Pycharm and it worked for me. Using python 3.7.6 and Pycharm 2020.1.

Comment: I was using python 3.8.2 in pycharm and I believe jupyter notebook is using python 3.7 as interpreter..

Comment: Yes I agree that a square would have both height and width as same. But this is just the intro video on the topic of classes in python.From what I learnt, when we ask for user input using "input" the values are stored as strings by default and we are supposed to convert to integers like variablename = int(input("Enter breadth")) I have just started to learn python.